Requesting Feedback on PCB Design for ESP32-C3, Sensors, and SIM808 Module
I’ve been working on a PCB design for my project, and I would appreciate any feedback or recommendations you can offer. The design includes:
ESP32-C3 for control and communication
SIM808 module for GPS and GPRS with SIM card support
MLX90614 for temperature measurement
MPU-9250 accelerometer
APDS-9960 proximity sensor
Power management using TP4056 for LiPo battery charging and switching between external power and battery
I've attached the schematic and PCB layout below. I am particularly interested in feedback on:
Power supply stability, especially for the SIM808, as I’ve included components for USB/battery power switching.
Any suggestions to optimize power consumption (using ESP32 deep sleep, etc.).
Ensuring proper communication via I2C between the ESP32-C3 and the sensors (pull-up resistor values, etc.).
Antenna placement and routing for SIM808 (GSM and GPS antennas).
Looking forward to your insights!
Thanks in advance for your help.



It looks like you ran auto place and auto route. The complexity of the circuit is fairly low so I’d hand route the board. You’ve used the same track thickness for all routes - high current and/or low inductance routes need thicker tracks.  The SIM808 should have a document with pcb design guidelines  - it’s not optional. I’d suggest using an ESP32 module rather than having to manage high frequency routes.  The schematic needs some tidying - it is challenging to decipher. What is L5 doing? Is this recommended by the manufacturer?
